# How to force fiddler to act as a system proxy?

Tags: proxy, web-deployment, fiddler

I am using tool Telerik Fiddler to monitor network traffic.

However, fiddler only captures traffic https or http but not tcp sockets.

How to make changes to make fiddler as a system wide proxy?

Such as Curl, Wget are not capture. I Just want to capture complete system network traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Fiddler is not intended for capturing tcp packets, since it is designed for inspecting the http protocol.
You should use a different tool, like WireShark.

If you are interested to capture http traffic from curl then you have to add a specif parameter (a curl parameter) for using a proxy (curl doesn't use the system proxy by default).

curl -x 127.0.0.1:8888 http://getthis/

in this way CURL will use Fiddler (on localhost port 8888) as a proxy.